# Android UI: how to replace one part of the screen while mainting the rest

Tags: android, user-interface, viewswitcher

I'm trying to achieve the effect that is part of the android google talk application on the chat window.
The effect is that there is a static top and bottom, but you can swipe between the various open chats that you have.

in other words, I'm trying to design a screen where there's a static section on top and on the bottom and a dynamic part in the center, think of a gallery app, where it shows you the title on top, a "show next image" button on the bottom and a picture in the center that gets replaced with the same transition you would see when switching between activities, only difference is that instead of an image, I need a more complex layout to be replaced in the center (a couple of text views and an image)

How should I go about doing that?
I thought about animations but it seems too complicated, and I thought about fragments but i don't know if it's supported on all versions or not and I also thought of drawing in runtime using the inflater but that doesnt let me do the "next activity" effect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the [`ViewFlipper`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewFlipper.html) class. It's what you're looking for. Here are some examples:

http://android-pro.blogspot.com/2010/09/using-view-flipper-in-android.html
http://www.androidpeople.com/android-viewflipper-example/

Answer (score 1):

You could use a RelativeLayout and have your header view aligned to the top of it, your footer view aligned to the bottom, and a middle Gallery view (or some layout that contains the views that will be changed) that is above the footer view and below the header view.

Answer (score 0):

IF you're not interested in the animations, you can just put all of your layouts in the screen and play with View.GONE/View.VISIBLE/View.INVISIBLE flags. use the  tag for nicer coding.